# Add unique ID's to input fields created with createElement method

Tags: javascript, forms, input, removechild, createelement

I'm trying to create a dynamic membership form, where I can send the ID of input fields as a shortcode into an email. The form generally begins with 2 fields (1 for name, 1 for email). I can then dynamically add new fields or remove with 2 control buttons.

I have managed to achieve adding and removing fields, ***but the issue I have is the ID of the new name field is showing "email_2", while the ID of the new email field is not being added***.

I also need help removing 2 fields at once with the removeField link. ***It appears to only be removing one field at at time***.

Here's my code...

```js
// set variables
let survey = document.querySelector(".survey");
let surveyInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".survey_field");
let addField = document.getElementById("add_field");
let removeField = document.getElementById("remove_field");

// increment id's with counter
let nameId = "name_";
let emailId = "email_";
let nameCounter = 1;
let emailCounter = 1;

// Add new text field and email field
addField.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let newNameField = document.createElement("input");
  newNameField.setAttribute("type", "text");
  newNameField.setAttribute("name", "survey_options");
  newNameField.setAttribute("class", "survey_field");
  newNameField.setAttribute("id", nameId + (++nameCounter));
  newNameField.setAttribute("placeholder", "Another Name");
  survey.appendChild(newNameField);
  let newEmailField = document.createElement("input");
  newEmailField.setAttribute("type", "email");
  newEmailField.setAttribute("name", "survey_options");
  newEmailField.setAttribute("class", "survey_field");
  newNameField.setAttribute("id", emailId + (++emailCounter));
  newEmailField.setAttribute("placeholder", "Another Email");
  survey.appendChild(newEmailField);
});

// Remove extra text field and email field at once
removeField.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (survey.children.length > 2) {
    survey.removeChild(survey.lastChild); // this removes only 1 field, how can I remove 2 at once?
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 38vw;
  margin: 3em auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 0 rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.2);
}

input[name="survey_options"] {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid 1px #e2e2e2;
  background: none;
  width: 15em;
  color: black;
}

input[name="survey_options"]:focus {
  outline: solid 1px lightgrey;
}

.controls {
  width: 25vw;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.svg-inline--fa {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#remove_field {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="survey">
    <input type="text" name="survey_options" class="survey_field" id="name_1" placeholder="Name" data-name="1" />
    <input type="email" name="survey_options" class="survey_field" id="email_1" placeholder="Email" data-email="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <a href="#" id="add_field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Field</a>
    <a href="#" id="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>Remove Field</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check the line of your code that's supposed to be adding the `id` attribute to the email field?

Comment: Thanks for the rearrange. If you look a the addField line, I have the (nameId + name counter) to solve for the "id" of the name field, and (emailId + email counter) to solve for the email "id".
But the result I'm getting is email_2 showing up in name "id" and nothing showing up in email "id".
Looks like the function is writing the "id" result twice, and wiping away the name "id".

Comment: Yeah, that's what my comment was trying to "hint" at I guess: The line of code that you think is setting the email id isn't adding the id to the email element, it's adding it to the name element. You should be doing `newEmailField.setAttribute("id", ...)`, not `newNameField.setAttribute("id", ...)` at the end of your function when you're setting your email attributes.

Comment: Thanks mate. D'you know I've looked at this for hours and didn't see my typo?

Please help me with removing 2 fields at once, if the user no longer wants to use that row.

Comment: I guess calling `survey.removeChild(survey.lastChild);` again should work...

Comment: https://prnt.sc/sF_zPoVjYhaw...
Realisitically, I'd prefer it removes the row at once, and not one field after the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254115/discussion-between-ladetunji-and-nick-parsons).

Answer (score 1):

You had a typo, but to avoid all that, just wrap the fields and clone

```js
// set variables
let survey = document.querySelector(".survey");
let addField = document.getElementById("add_field");
let removeField = document.getElementById("remove_field");

const renumber = () => {
  [...survey.children]
  .forEach((div, i) => div.querySelectorAll('input')
    .forEach(inp => {
      // renumber the IDs and data-name
      const index = i + 1;
      inp.id = `${inp.name}_${index}`;
      inp.dataset[inp.placeholder.toLowerCase()] = index;
    })
  )
};
// Add new text field and email field
addField.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const div = survey.lastElementChild.cloneNode(true);
  div.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(inp => inp.value = ""); // clear the value from the cloned fields
  survey.appendChild(div);
  renumber();
});

// Remove extra text field and email field at once
removeField.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (survey.children.length > 1) {
    survey.removeChild(survey.lastChild); // this removes the div
    renumber();
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 38vw;
  margin: 3em auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 0 rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.2);
}

input[name="survey_options"] {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid 1px #e2e2e2;
  background: none;
  width: 15em;
  color: black;
}

input[name="survey_options"]:focus {
  outline: solid 1px lightgrey;
}

.controls {
  width: 25vw;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.svg-inline--fa {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#remove_field {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="survey">
    <div class="item">
      <input type="text" name="survey_options" class="survey_field" placeholder="Name" data-name="1" />
      <input type="email" name="survey_options" class="survey_field" placeholder="Email" data-email="1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <a href="#" id="add_field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Field</a>
    <a href="#" id="remove_field"><i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>Remove Field</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cloning the node will add the value's of the old node also to newly created nodes.

Comment: @Basiljose You are correct. I have added a clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer M. This woulda been perfect, but it doesn't generate new unique "ids" for the input fields. It doesn't even generate any ids at all and I need them.

Comment: My code did not need IDs. You can create IDs in this loop: `div.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(inp => inp.value="");` Tell me why you need IDs and I can likely get rid of them there too

Comment: I have updated to add an ID and rewrite it when added or removed

Comment: Hi M, so I noticed you don't have `id` in your input HTML. That's the `id` I'm trying to change and renumber, and not the div.item `id`. Kinda why I added the data attribute too, in case I needed to use it for some code

Comment: I added data-name too

Answer (score 0):

In the add field event listener variable name was wrong

```
// set variables
 let survey = document.querySelector(".survey");
 let surveyInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".survey_field");
 let addField = document.getElementById("add_field");
 let removeField = document.getElementById("remove_field");
 
 // increment id's with counter
 let nameId = "name_";
 let emailId = "email_";
 let nameCounter = 1;
 let emailCounter = 1;
 
 // Add new text field and email field
 addField.addEventListener("click", () => {
   let newNameField = document.createElement("input");
   newNameField.setAttribute("type", "text");
   newNameField.setAttribute("name", "survey_options");
   newNameField.setAttribute("class", "survey_field");
   newNameField.setAttribute("id", nameId + (++nameCounter));
   newNameField.setAttribute("placeholder", "Another Name");
   survey.appendChild(newNameField);
 
   let newEmailField = document.createElement("input");
   newEmailField.setAttribute("type", "email");
   newEmailField.setAttribute("name", "survey_options");
   newEmailField.setAttribute("class", "survey_field");
   newEmailField.setAttribute("id", emailId + (++emailCounter));
   newEmailField.setAttribute("placeholder", "Another Email");
   survey.appendChild(newEmailField);
 
 });
 
 // Remove extra text field and email field at once
 removeField.addEventListener("click", () => {
   if (survey.children.length > 2) {
     let last_id = survey.lastChild.id.split("_")[1];
     if (last_id) {
       let nameFieldToRemove = document.getElementById(`name_${last_id}`)
       survey.removeChild(survey.lastChild); // this removes only 1 field, how can I remove 2 at once?
       survey.removeChild(nameFieldToRemove);
     }
   }
 });
```

Remove both added fields function also updated
you can either use `removeChild` twice or use the above method to find the element and remove it

Comment: Thanks Basil, I'll give this a try.
Does the .split literally mean to separate the "id" attribute at the point where the _ was written to leave the number 1 or 2?

Comment: yes, with that id again construct the name+id and find that element and remove

Comment: Please do not answer typo-type questions unless you improve them. Instead if you are allowed, vote to close

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion ! I have modified the remove event listener  thats why i have posted the anwser

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @mplungjan and @basil-jose for your solutions. It really opened my mind to problem-solving. I ran the question through Bard AI and then iterated a few times to get this.

```
// Get the HTML elements
const survey = document.querySelector(".survey");
const addField = document.getElementById("add_field");
const removeField = document.getElementById("remove_field");

addField.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Get the current count of text and email input fields
  const nameCount = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]").length;
  const emailCount = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=email]").length;

  // Create a new text input element
  const nameField = document.createElement("input");
  nameField.type = "text";
  nameField.name = "survey_options";
  nameField.setAttribute("class", "survey_field");
  nameField.placeholder = "New Name";
  nameField.id = `name_${nameCount + 1}`;

  // Create a new email input element
  const emailField = document.createElement("input");
  emailField.type = "email";
  emailField.name = "survey_options";
  emailField.setAttribute("class", "survey_field");
  emailField.placeholder = "New Email";
  emailField.id = `email_${emailCount + 1}`;

  // Append the text and email input elements to the button element
  survey.appendChild(nameField);
  survey.appendChild(emailField);
});

removeField.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Get the last two input fields in the document
  const lastEmailField = survey.lastElementChild;
  const lastNameField = lastEmailField.previousElementSibling;

  // Remove the input fields from the document
  if (survey.children.length > 2) {
    lastNameField.remove();
    lastEmailField.remove();
  }
});
```

The nameCount and emailCount variables were gamechangers, as it solved the issue I noticed in @basil-jose's solution where whenever I removed a row of fields, the inputCount never reduced and only kept increasing after subsequent clicks - meaning I could have 3 rows, but the inputs in memory are probably 12.

The sibling method also helped with picking inputs either side of the lastChild, making the removal process simple too.

Thanks again.